# Allow user to use brclt-like commands without sudo

Tags: sudo, ip, bridge, privileges

I have script that using python library(pyroute2) to create and manage bridge. But I don't want to run this script as root and want to allow some specific user to have required privileges.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sudo` to grant a single user passwordless access to a single command by adding the following to your sudoers file (edit it with `sudo visudo`).

```
username ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN=+eip
```

Replacing `username` with the desired username and ensuring the path is correct. You may or may not be required to restart the application/relogin as that user for the change to take effect.

You can see if the user has passwordless access to the desired command by logging in as them with `sudo -iu username` and attempting to run the command with `sudo setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN=+eip`.

Answer (score 1):

It supposed to be sudo setcap CAP_NET_ADMIN=+eip.